# java script data transfer/assign between complex objects

Tags: javascript

I have two objects `customer` and `customerDisplay` with below structure.

I would like to get the data transfer from `customer` object to `customerDisplay`. Is there any built in function to achieve this??

I tried doing traditional for loop,however assigning/adding  object to `customerdisplay` is always resulting in syntax error that unable to add element. Please advise.

```
Customer
 |
 |Properties
 |Address
    |
    |Street
    |Postal Code
 |Transactions      

CustomerDisplay
 |
 |Properties
 |List(DataSet)
        |Dataset1
            |Name(Address)
            |Key
            |Value
        |Dataset2
            |Name(Transactions)
            |Key
            |ValueCustomer
 |
 |Properties
 |Address
    |
    |Street
    |Postal Code
 |Transactions
```

---

```
CustomerDisplay
 |
 |Properties
 |List(DataSet)
        |Dataset1
            |Name(Address)
            |Key
            |Value
        |Dataset2
            |Name(Transactions)
            |Key
            |Value
```

Below is the json format

```
Customer: {
      property: [
        { label: 'xxxx', name: 'xxxxxx', value: ['xxxxx'] },
        { label: 'xxxxxxxx', name: 'xxxxx', value: ['xxxxxxxxxxx'] }
      ],
      Address: [
        {

          labels: [
            { key: 'name', value: 'Street Name' },
            { key: 'xxxxxxx', value: 'xxxx' }
          ],
          data: [{
            dataEntry: [
              { key: 'name', value: 'Credit Card / Line of Credit Statement' },
              { key: 'xxxx', value: 'xxxx' }
            ]}]
        }

      ]
    }



CustomerDisplay: {
      property: [
        { label: 'xxxx', name: 'xxxxxx', value: ['xxxxx'] },
        { label: 'xxxxxxxx', name: 'xxxxx', value: ['xxxxxxxxxxx'] }
      ],
      dataSet: [
        {
          dataSetName: 'Address',
          labels: [
            { key: 'name', value: 'Street Name' },
            { key: 'xxxxxxx', value: 'xxxx' }
          ],
          data: [{
            dataEntry: [
              { key: 'name', value: 'Credit Card / Line of Credit Statement' },
              { key: 'xxxx', value: 'xxxx' }
            ]}]
        }

      ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you post an example of each object? (like with JSON notation, not with pipes)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with relevant code you tried. Click the `<>` snippet editor and provide a runnable example

Comment: added json format in the original post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your structure looks like it represents the tables in your database (flattened representation). Instead of *moving* data from one object to another, I would rather keep the data "as is" in its flattened form and then have a *function* in my `Customer` object that returns the corresponding `CustomerDisplay` object (something like `Customer.getDisplay()` or similar).

Comment: yeah i know that the object modification is easy in java layer.However we need this to be in front end in order to generalise the aproach.Hence would like to do this in javascript

Comment: Yes... I'm talking about Javascript, of course. Why not create such a function within your customer objects right after parsing your Json data? I personally like this approach because you can easily update the data without recreating many nested objects. Usually I also implement a localStorage-based cache for rarely changing data when I'm at it.